# R- merge two data frames but some values have semi colon in them

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe

One of my data frame (df1) has a column like this:

```
ID
AB
CD;EF
IJ
KL
MN
OP;WX
WW
YZ
```

The other data frame (df2) has the following format (this is a very big data table):

```
myIDColumn  someName    somevalue
AB  gsdfg   123
CD  tfgsdfg 234
EF  sfdgsf  365
GH  gdfgb   53453
IJ  sr  64564
KL  sfsdv   4234234
MN  ewrwe   5
OP  dsfsss  3453
QR  gggg    667
ST  dss 7567
UV  hhhhjf  55
WX  dfadasad    8657
YZ  ghfgh   1234
ABC gdgfg 234455
VCB hgjkk 5555667
```

I would like to merge the dataframes based on my df1 but how can i solve the issue
of the semicolon on this paticular join. Is there a way to join these dataframes using regular expressions?

My desired output:

> ```
> ID    someName    somevalue
> AB    gsdfg   123
> CD;EF tfgsdfg,sfdgsf  234,365
> IJ    sr  64564
> KL    sfsdv   4234234
> MN    ewrwe   5
> OP;WX dsfsss,dfadasad 3453,8657
> WW        
> YZ    dfadasad    8657
> TT
> ```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2 steps, similar to the posted solution but in more compacted way.

1. merge the 2 data.frame
2. Then transform the rows containing ";"

Here the code:

```
##step1
mm <- merge(df2,df1,by.y='ID',by.x='myIDColumn',all.y=TRUE)
## step2
rr <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(mm$myIDColumn[grep(';',mm$myIDColumn)],';'),
       function(x){
            res <- paste(df2[df2$myIDColumn==x[1],],
                  df2[df2$myIDColumn==x[2],],
                  sep=',')
            res[1] <- paste(x,collapse=';')
            res}))
mm[grep(';',mm$myIDColumn),]  <- rr

 myIDColumn        someName somevalue
1         AB           gsdfg       123
2      CD;EF  tfgsdfg,sfdgsf   234,365
3         IJ              sr     64564
4         KL           sfsdv   4234234
5         MN           ewrwe         5
6      OP;WX dsfsss,dfadasad 3453,8657
7         WW            <NA>      <NA>
8         YZ           ghfgh      1234
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. When i try it on my real data, i get the following error: Error in strsplit(mm$UniProtID[grep(";", mm$UniProtID)], ";") : 
  non-character argument

Comment: Did you try to coerce it to character, `mm$UniProtID <- as.character(mm$UniProtID)`

Comment: thanks..that solved the problem but as i debug further i am getting this error: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, grep(";", mm$UniProtID), , value = c("P05386;P05387",  : 
  replacement has 6 items, need 10

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more comment regarding res <- paste(df2[df2$myIDColumn==x[1],], df2[df2$myIDColumn==x[2],],sep=',') part of the code. What if i have more than 2 elements separated by ;. How can i dynamically assign that? For example CD;EF;IJ and OP;WX.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a compact solution. Beware that all fields will be converted to characters since there is no other way to store two integers in one element otherwise. In case there are values in `df1$ID` that are missing in `df2$miIDColumn` you'll get a `"character(0)"` value there.

```
IDs <- strsplit(df1$ID, ";")
mrg <- foreach(x=IDs, .combine=rbind) %do% {
    pieces <- lapply(x, function(y) df2[df2$myIDColumn %in% y,])
    do.call(paste, c(pieces, list(sep=",")))
}
dimnames(mrg) <- list(NULL, colnames(df2))
```

Here's the output (`mrg` is a matrix btw):

```
     myIDColumn     someName          somevalue   
[1,] "AB"           "gsdfg"           "123"       
[2,] "CD,EF"        "tfgsdfg,sfdgsf"  "234,365"   
[3,] "IJ"           "sr"              "64564"     
[4,] "KL"           "sfsdv"           "4234234"   
[5,] "MN"           "ewrwe"           "5"         
[6,] "OP,WX"        "dsfsss,dfadasad" "3453,8657" 
[7,] "character(0)" "character(0)"    "integer(0)"
[8,] "YZ"           "ghfgh"           "1234"
```

Comment: I assume that the you are using `foreach` package here. Also, Beware you change the ";" ID to a ',' ones. +1 because I find this solution out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a strategy that involves separating `df1` into two new dataframes (one that you'll merge to `df2` sort of normally and one that has semicolon `ID` values, which is harder to deal with).

```
l <- grep(";",df1$ID) # semicolon lines
nl <- which(!grepl(";",df1$ID)) # non-semicolon lines

# merge non-semicolon lines
newdfA <- merge(df1[nl,],df2,all.x=TRUE)

# merge semicolon lines
tmpdf1 <- df1[l,]
split <- strsplit(tmpdf1$ID,";")

### This seems sloppy, but should work
newdfB <- data.frame(t(sapply(split, FUN=
    function(x){
    tmprows <- df2[df2$ID %in% x,]
    return(c(   paste0(tmprows[,1],collapse=";"),
            paste0(tmprows[,2],collapse=","),
            paste0(tmprows[,3],collapse=",") ))
    } )))
colnames(newdfB) <- c("ID","someName","someValue")

# merge everything back together
newdf <- merge(newdfA, newdfB, all=TRUE)
```